# Hiding a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, hide

In my latest program, there is a button that displays some input popup boxes when clicked. After these boxes go away, how do I hide the button?

Comment: how are you making the boxes go away? If you are making them go away wih javascript, it is usually very simple to make something else dissapear.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can [set its `visibility` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) to `hidden`.

Here is a little demonstration, where one button is used to toggle the other one:

```
<input type="button" id="toggler" value="Toggler" onClick="action();" />
<input type="button" id="togglee" value="Togglee" />

<script>
    var hidden = false;
    function action() {
        hidden = !hidden;
        if(hidden) {
            document.getElementById('togglee').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('togglee').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: element.classList.add("hide-me"); can anyone explain this can hide the element ?

Answer (score 25):

```
visibility="hidden"
```

is very useful, but it will still take up space on the page. You can also use

```
display="none"
```

because that will not only hide the object, but make it so that it doesn't take up space until it is displayed. (Also keep in mind that display's opposite is "block," not "visible")

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should remove it

```
document.getElementById('x').style.visibility='hidden';
```

If you are going to do alot of this dom manipulation might be worth looking at jquery

Comment: This doesn't remove the dom but hides it.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('btnID').style.visibility='hidden';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Your code to make the box goes here... call it box
box.id="foo";
//Your code to remove the box goes here
document.getElementById("foo").style.display="none";
```

of course if you are doing a lot of stuff like this, use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)

Answer (score 2):

**If the space on that page is not disabled then put your button inside a div.**

```
<div id="a1">
<button>Click here</button>
</div>
```

Using Jquery:

```
<script language="javascript">
$("#a1").hide();
</script>
```

Using JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById("a1").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("a1").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you press the button so it should call function that will alert message. so after alert put `style visible` property . 
you can achieve it using

```js
function OpenAlert(){
        alert("Getting the message");
        document.getElementById("getMessage").style.visibility="hidden";
        
    }
```

```html
 <input type="button" id="getMessage" name="GetMessage" value="GetMessage" onclick="OpenAlert()"/>
```

Hope this will help . Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```js
function popAlert(){
        alert("Button will be hidden on click");
        document.getElementById("getMessage").style.visibility="hidden";
        
    }
```

```css
   h1 {
            color: #0000ff;
        }
```

```html
<h1>KIAAT</h1>
    <b>Hiding a button in Javascript after click</b>
    <br><br>
<input type="button" id="getMessage"  value="Hide Button OnClick" onclick="popAlert()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using jQuery I would suggest using it. If you do, you would want to do something like:

```
$( 'button' ).on(
   'click'
   function (  )
   {
       $( this ).hide(  );
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $('#btn_hide').click( function () {
      $('#btn_hide').hide();
    });
</script>
<input type="button" id="btn_hide"/>
```

this will be enough

Comment: Line 3 is missing a close quote

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
btnID.hidden = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
while ((new Date().getTime() - start) < 1000){
  } //for 1 sec delay
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.