# is it possible to hide div when another button is click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I am trying to hide the `div`'s when different buttons are clicked but I don't know how to. *(So when 'Test 1' is clicked it should hide 'Test 2' Div and vice versa)* I checked here and on Google but couldn't find an answer for it.

Javascript :

```
function showHide(divId) {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    if (theDiv.style.display == "none") {
        theDiv.style.display = "";
    } else {
        theDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="button" onclick="showHide('hidethis')" value="Test It"> 
<div id="hidethis" style="display:none">
<h1>TEST ME!</h1>>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="showHide('hidethis2')" value="Test It 2"> 
<div id="hidethis2" style="display:none">
<h1>TEST MEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE 2!</h1>
</div>
```

#### JSFIDDLE: is not doing it here but works locally

http://jsfiddle.net/S5JzK/

Comment: I would recomment using Jquery, check  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript

Comment: try somthing like this: http://jsfiddle.net/S5JzK/1/

Comment: @Priyajain - thanks for the JS but for some reason jQuery does not work in the project that I'm working on. It only allows me to use JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="button" onclick="showHide('hidethis')" value="Test It" /> 
<div id="hidethis" style="display:none">
<h1>TEST ME!</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="showHide('hidethis2')" value="Test It 2"> 
<div id="hidethis2" style="display:none">
<h1>TEST MEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE 2!</h1>
</div>


function showHide(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
```

Check the Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/S5JzK/7/

Comment: Thanks for that possible Fix - It partly works but when I click another button, it does not Hide the Div. For Example - `Test It` button is `clicked` it shows `hidethis Div` and when `Test It 2` button is clicked it should hide `hidethis Div` and show `hidethis2 Div`. Hope it makes sense :) thanks again :)

Comment: Change Function to this

function showHide(divId) {
    $("div").hide();
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
}
This is just a fix and you have to change according to scenario.

If you are looking for tab structure, then have a look at below fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/zEwQz/500/

Comment: thanks for that - your fix partly worked ;) but it hides `All` the `Divs` in the page. Is it possible to stop that? thanks again :)

Comment: thanks for that, Here's the http://jsfiddle.net/S5JzK/13/ link to my initail code. :)

Comment: awesome man, that worked like a charm :). One last thing if possible only, can v hide the respective divs by click the buttons? not necessary but only if possible :) thanks again for swift help! :)

Comment: Yes, all you have to do is to check when to call the last line of function. If its not called then it will hide too. Set a custom attribute to check that or whatever method works for you.

Comment: thanks for that, could you please help out with JSFiddle please? I'm not very good with JavaScript / jQuery if you don't mind please? thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

1. To it work in fiddle, in your example, you need to select (No wrap - in head) on the left.
2. Look the example below, using pure javascript:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="showHide('hidethis')" value="Test It"> 
<div id="hidethis" style="display:none">
    <h1>TEST ME!</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="showHide('hidethis2')" value="Test It 2"> 
<div id="hidethis2" style="display:none">
    <h1>TEST MEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE 2!</h1>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function showHide(divId) {

    /* Hide all divs */
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    /* Set display */
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    theDiv.style.display = "";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S5JzK/9/

**ANOTHER JAVASCRIPT EXAMPLE**

```
function showHide(divId) {

    /* Hide the divs that you want */
    var div1 = document.getElementById('#hidethis');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('#hidethis2');

    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "none";

    /* Set display */
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(divId);
    theDiv.style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: better to use toggle function.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I just wanted to illustrate with a pure javascript.

Comment: @guinatal- thanks for the possible fix - You're right about the JavaScript. For some reason in VS 2008, it only allows me to use JavaScript and not jQuery. Your code works fine and does what it should but it hides all the div on the page is it possible to just hide the two divs mentioned in the code above? For Example - when `Test It` button is clicked it shows `hidethis Div` and when `Test It 2` button is clicked it should hide `hidethis Div` and show `hidethis2 Div` and vice versa. Hope it makes sense :) thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it works well and so simple,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.manageDiv{
    display:none;

}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
<input type="button" class="testButton" value="Test It" /> 
<input type="button" class="testButton" value="Test It 2" /> 

<div id="hidethis2" class="manageDiv">
<h1>TEST MEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE 2!</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>

$(function(){    
    $(".testButton").on("click", function(){
                        $("#hidethis2").toggleClass("manageDiv");

                        });
});
```

Comment: thanks for that :) it doesn't work on mine? Is it possible to do this with JavaScript? Because jQuery doesn't work on my PC. thanks again :)

Comment: Jquery will work in all browsers...Just include this url in the script tag http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js or download the latest version of jquery from http://jquery.com/download/, include it in script tag and then access the jquery functions.

Comment: thanks, I tried that initially, strange though that it should work. But for some reason it ain't working. Hence, I'm stuck with JavaScript. Any possible way to convert your jQuery code to JavaScript? thanks again :)

Comment: Ya sure, i have the solution in javascript as well...let me share the fiddle for you..

Comment: Hey, that's great man, works fine on the JS but doesn't work on my machine. Don't need function at the top do you? thanks :)

Comment: Hope you might have disabled the javascript in your browser. Enable it and proceed with the script. Thanks :)

Comment: I checked it and it is enabled.. let me check what else is going on :) - thanks again for your help! your code is great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
function showHideDiv(divId, bShow) {
  if (bShow) {
    $("#" + divId).show();
  } else {
    $("#" + divId).hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: `$("#"+divId).toggle(bShow)` does the same thing in one line.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems fine. are you sure you enter the function upon click? try adding a breakpoint using developer tools or an alert.

Anyways, I see you tagged this post with jquery. you can you it to do the task more elegantly.

```
   $("#" + theDiv).hide();
```

or for showing it:

```
   $("#" + theDiv).show();
```

Comment: thanks for that :) I tried it but it didn't work for me. Could you provide an example please? thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"JSFIDDLE: is not doing it here but works locally"*

Yes, because by default jsfiddle wraps your JS in an onload handler, which means the function declaration is local to that handler. Inline html attribute event handlers like your `onclick="showHide('hidethis')"` can only call global functions.

Under jsfiddle's *Frameworks & Extensions* heading there's a drop-down where you can change the default "onload" to "No wrap - in head" (or "No wrap - in body"). That'll make your function declaration global as in your local implementation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S5JzK/8/

Comment: thanks for the information, makes a lot of sense now. Thanks again and I will give it a test :) Awesome man!