# Javascript - Hiding Button if not logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a website using an obsolete e-commerce CMS, really ties my hands behind my back because of it's lack of options and my beginner ability with JS and jQ.

On this site, we need to hide Prices and Add to Cart buttons if the user is not logged in. I have a script that has worked for me in the past that checks the users cookies. But after editing this script for the new site, it proves to not work.

I am probably messing up something very simple in the syntax, so if someone can take a quick look at my script and let me know where I am going wrong that would be great!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayAuthorizedContent(name) {
    var cookies=document.cookie;
    var start = cookies.indexOf(name + "=");
    var name = "";
    var start1; 
    var end1;
    var tmp;
    var signed_in = -1;

    if (start != -1) {
        start = cookies.indexOf("=", start) +1;
        var end = cookies.indexOf("|", start);
        if (end != -1) {
            signed_in = cookies.indexOf("|yes", start);
            name = unescape(cookies.substring(start,end-1));
            if (signed_in != -1) { 
                $('.loginFilter').show();
            }
        }
    }
    if (signed_in == -1) {
        $('.loginFilter').empty();
        $('.addMessage').each(function(){
            $(this).append('Requires Wholesale Account to Purchase.<br><br><a href=\"#\" class=\"applyLink\">Apply Here<\/a>');
            $(this).show();
        });
    }
}
DisplayAuthorizedContent("ss_reg_000778370");
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<div class="loginFilter addMessage"><a href="#">Add to Cart Example</a></div>
```

Comment: It might not be what you want to hear but I feel obliged to mention this, is there server-side logic that looks to check if you're logged in? If not this is a very bad idea. All I need to do is go to your website, press F12 in my browser, remove the display: none attributes, and boom, I'm logged in! Security restrictions need to be handled server-side Client side means you 100% trust the browser to do what you tell it to do which is incredibly frightening.

Comment: To reinforce what @dman2306 says, (1) the client should offer a sign-in/sign-out interface, which makes a request to the server (2) signed-in/signed-out should be a server-side state, (3) the server should "inform" the client of the server-side state, typically by including/withholding content. The client should not be able to override the server-side state by determining it for itself (eg reading a cookie), nor emulate the logged-in state by making hidden content visible.

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually I have already expressed my concerns with the client and my boss. Neither are very concerned about the security... -_-

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the button might not be hidden on page load.

Guessing you'd need something like jQuery:

```
$('.loginFilter').hide();
```

you can hide the button with javascript (you'd have to add the `id = 'button'` to HTML)

```
document.getElementById('button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

here are some hide/show references:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp
[Hiding a button in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript)