# Dynamically change Button functionality on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I would like to have a single button that does 2 functions without having to refresh or visit another page. 1. First will be **Add to Cart** button when clicked it will add a product to a cart and once the product is added to cart the button should 2. change to **Remove from cart** and when clicked **Remove from cart** button it should remove the item from cart and again change the button again back to **Add to cart**.

Right now I am using very simple onclick event button

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse btn-embossed" onclick="ajaxSubmit('/add/product/<?php echo $productId; ?>/"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

Product can be removed with url below

```
/remove/product/<?php echo $productId ?>/
```

I have already tried several options from other forums but I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: The easiest way is to use two buttons and hide one. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript for details how to hide a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to move your ajax call from onclick event so you don't need o duplicate long code. Second add parameters like current action and id to `data` for jQuery access.

```js
$('.product-btn').click(function(){
 if($(this).attr('data-action')=="add"){
     ajaxSubmit('/add/product/'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/');
          $(this).attr('data-action','remove');
          $(this).children('span').html('Remove from cart');
  }else{
   ajaxSubmit('/remove/product/'+$(this).attr('data-id')+'/');
        $(this).attr('data-action','add');
        $(this).children('span').html('Add to cart');
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-inverse btn-embossed product-btn" data-action="add" data-id="<?php echo $productId; ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

Comment: I think jQuery is causing conflict as I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null` error

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxSubmit is not defined` error.