# Adaptive Button Layouts HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, user-interface

I'm trying to get buttons to be adaptive such that when the screen orientation changes (on a mobile device) the button layout changes. The intention is just to keep the website user friendly regardless of how the device is being used. The sizing of the buttons I can do using css that I set in scripts. That's not hard, but I'm not quite sure of two things:

1. How to arrange the buttons in HTML such that they will be easy to manipulate with Javascript, etc. when the orientation or aspect ratio changes. I'm not even sure how to do the Javascript manipulations.
2. What kind of scripting to use to trigger the button sizing/layout code every time the aspect ratio or screen orientation changes (i.e. when your device goes from vertical to horizontal view).

My current HTML layout code is as follows:

```
<div class="button_container">

    <div id="toprow" class="buttons">
        <button id="btn1" class="topbuttons">Button1</button>
        <button id="btn2" class="topbuttons">Button2</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="midrow" class="buttons">
        <button id="btn3">Button3</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="bottomrow" class="buttons">
        <button id="btn4" class="bottombuttons">Button4</button>
        <button id="btn5" class="bottombuttons">Button5</button>
        <button id="btn6" class="bottombuttons">Button6</button>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look in a portrait aspect ratio (i.e. on a smartphone):
[image]

This is how I want it to look in a landscape aspect ratio (i.e. on a PC):
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated as I am relatively new to web development.

Comment: did you know about media queries? what have you tried? where is your Css?

Comment: @DaniP I don't know about media queries. I've just used CSS in a script to size the buttons for the portrait orientation only. I've set things like margin, padding, width, height. My original idea was to have another <div> called "button_container2" and then hiding that one unless I want the horizontal view using the method in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript). But I'm sure that there is a more efficient way.

Comment: The answer for you will be media queries, that way youn can control the CSS of elements based on many different points like device-width or device-orientation or window size ... I would recommend start there and define your breakpoints

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look into that. It seems like there are some browser compatibility issues with that. But it does seem a better idea than my plan.

Comment: The browser comp is almost full http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries unless you try to support ie8 or below which needs some additional work but there is a polify to make media queries work there. Try with that media queries and if you have any problem we are here to help

Comment: @DaniP, I've found that using a combination of media queries and [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) works quite easily. The only problem I have with media queries is that I cannot get a single div to be sized for the whole available space on the browser (i.e without scrolling). I've tried `.grid_main { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }` but it never sizes correctly. Any ideas on how to do this without using `px` values in the CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

As is suggested in the comments, media queries are definitely the way to handle this.

You can also look into using css flexbox, which helps in flowing content around when you shrink the screen or move onto a mobile device. Take a look at the following for more info: [Visual Guide to CSS3 Flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties).