# Loader with python & flask

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I make a premise: I'm working on a school project and the technologies that I can use are: python, flask, bootstrap, JavaScript and JQuery.

I have a button (that I will call to "Update Product") that "onclick" must enable one of these buttons:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loading_buttons.asp, the "Update Product" button must be hidden and must call a function in python (example: updateProducts ()).
At the end of this function (the function returns ok or ko), I return the message (using flash), but I do not know how to hide the Loading button and show the "Update Product" button again.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.
When you render the template in python you could pass a variable to control the visibility of the button.

```
render_template('page.html', visible=True)
```

Then, on your page perhaps something like this (found at [Hiding a button in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript) and adapted)

```
<script>
var hidden = {{ visible|safe }};
function action() {
    if(hidden) {
        document.getElementById('button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

You can also change the variable with an onclick function on then page itself.
Your button to call a python function could look something like this.

```
<input type="button" id="toggler" value="Toggler" onClick="/funcionName" />
```

Remember to use the `@app.route("/functionName")` before the python function.

Hope this is close to what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to achieve this.

1. Add loading button with hidden class.
2. When you click update Product button, following things should happen.

   `$(".update_button").on("click", function(e){
       $(".loading_button").show(); // show loading button
       $(".update_button").hide(); // hide update button
       $.ajax({}) // send ajax request to update product, on success, hide loader and show update button
   });`