# Button not appearing when game ends

Tags: javascript, html

I want a restart a game after it ends with a button, but I don’t want it to appear until you crash.

I have tried this code:

```
if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop;
            var button = document.createElement("button");
            button.innerHTML = "Restart";
            var body = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0];
            body.appendChild(button);
            return;
        }
```

The button does not appear. Can you help me fix this?
Update: I have tried making the button be hidden and then not, but that doesn’t work. I have tried doing it the way that someone (sorry) suggested and that created and infinite number of buttons.

Comment: have the button on the page with hidden attribute, and then unhide it when you would like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding a button in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript)

Comment: I have gotten the button to appear,  now I just need it to not make and infinite number of them.

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear because there is a little error in your script.

```
 var body = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0];
```

should be

```
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

As a side note, if you want to append a dynamically created html element to the body it's sufficient to write:

```
document.body.appendChild(button);
```