# How can I display a button only during a specific time period?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET site where I need to have a button for submitting payments only during specified open time windows. The button should only be visible to customers from December 1st to January 31st, and invisible during the rest of the year. How can I control this?

So far I have drafted a very simple JS function.

```
function TimePeriod() {
    var now = new DateTime();

    if (now.Month == 1 || now.Month == 12) {
        $("#payBtn").css('display', 'visible');
    }
    else {
        $("#payBtn").css('display', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track / if this is enough, so any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: i think you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript) . is this what you looking for? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what `new DateTime()` is, so I am assuming you mean `new Date()`. You also need to use `.getMonth()` that returns `0` to `11` as a results. You can use `.show()` or `.hide()`.

```js
$(function() {
  function TimePeriod() {
    var now = new Date();

    if ((now.getMonth() + 1) == 1 || (now.getMonth() + 1) == 12) {
      $("#payBtn").show();
    } else {
      $("#payBtn").hide();
    }
  }

  TimePeriod();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border: 1px solid #000;">
  <button id="payBtn">Pay</button>
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

For reference, in CSS, `display` can use `block` or `hidden` not `visible`.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp