# Hidden input when the radio button is changed does not work

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have three radio buttons;

- when I click on the first I want the inputs of the other two not to be visible;
- when I click on the second I want the input of the third not to be visible (the first has no input)
- when I click on the third I want the second input (ie the one related to the second radio button) not visible.

The code I wrote does not work well; when I click on the first radio button it only hides the input of the third radio button but not the second one as well. Also when I click on the third, the input of the second radio button does not disappear.

```
<div id="fieldinput" class="mt-5">
                    <label for="discount" class="form-label">Sconto</label>
                    <div class="form-check my-4 mb-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioNoDisconunt" value="nodiscount" checked onclick="showinputfield(value);">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioNoDisconunt"> No discount </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check my-4 mb-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioRelativeDisconunt" value="relativediscount" onclick="showinputfield(value);">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioRelativeDisconunt"> Relative Disconunt in %</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control p-3 inputrelativediscount" name="" value="">                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check my-4 mb-3">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioAbsoluteDisconunt" value="absolutediscount" onclick="showinputfield(value);">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioAbsoluteDisconunt"> Absolute Disconunt </label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control p-3 inputabsolutediscount" name="" value="">
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

```
window.showinputfield = function (check) {
    let input = document.getElementById('fieldinput');
    if(check=="nodiscount"){        
        input.classList.add("visible");
    }
    else if(check=="relativediscount"){        
        input.classList.add("visible");
    }else {
        input.classList.remove("visible");
    }
}
```

```
.visible .inputrelativediscount{
    display: block;
}

.visible .inputabsolutediscount{
    display: none;
}
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Hope this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685107/hiding-a-button-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I make this one for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <style>
        .inputs{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
<body>


    <div id="fieldinput" class="mt-5">
        <label for="discount" class="form-label">Sconto</label>
        <div class="form-check my-4 mb-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioNoDisconunt" value="nodiscount" checked onclick="showinputfield(value);">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioNoDisconunt"> No discount </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check my-4 mb-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioRelativeDisconunt" value="relativediscount" onclick="showinputfield(value);">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioRelativeDisconunt"> Relative Disconunt in %</label>
            <input type="number" id="inputrelativediscount" class="form-control p-3 inputs" name="" value="">                    
        </div>
        <div class="form-check my-4 mb-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="discount" id="flexRadioAbsoluteDisconunt" value="absolutediscount" onclick="showinputfield(value);">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioAbsoluteDisconunt"> Absolute Disconunt </label>
            <input type="number" id="inputabsolutediscount" class="form-control p-3 inputs" name="" value="">
        </div>  
    </div>

    <script>


function showinputfield(check){
    let noDiscount = document.getElementById("flexRadioNoDisconunt");
    let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('inputs');
    let relativeDiscount = document.getElementById("inputrelativediscount");
    let absoluteDiscount = document.getElementById("inputabsolutediscount");
    if(check === "nodiscount"){
        relativeDiscount.style.display = 'none';
        absoluteDiscount.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(check === 'relativediscount'){
        relativeDiscount.style.display = 'block';
        absoluteDiscount.style.display = 'none';
        
    }
    else if(check === 'absolutediscount'){
        absoluteDiscount.style.display = 'block';
        relativeDiscount.style.display = 'none';

    }
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you do with add and remove?

Comment: doing with add and remove will increase the code and it is not recommended to do that way or you need to change the approach to use add and remove classlist.